# onPrint function or method of recording when user prints

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides-api

Can anybody suggest a way of recording when user prints slide, I thought that there might be an `onPrint` function, but it doesn't look like there is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's a `window.print()` in client side JavaScript but nothing for the server side.  It's hard to tell what you want because you haven't supplied any code.

Comment: There is no trigger for this, but if you give more details about what you want to accomplish and why, someone might be able to provide a valid workaround for you.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  Trying to create an event log when the user Prints the slides.  I can then make the assumption that the slides are displayed in each of our sites.  Thanks

Comment: `I can then make the assumption that the slides are displayed in each of our sites`. Can you expand on this? I'm not sure I understand you.